# Blob Trigger: using Azure Active Directory (AAD) integration instead of Storage Connection String

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to setup a [Blob Triggered Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp), but I do not wish to share the Connection String to my storage account with said Function.

Theoretically, since Blob Storage is [integrated with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad), it should be possible to provide the right RBAC permissions on my Blob Containers so that the [Function's identity (Managed Service Identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity) has whatever permissions are necessary to create the trigger and read from the blobs.

However, I haven't found a way to achieve this.

All the options I have found involve the use of a full Connection String, which would give full control of the Storage Account to the Function.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If you not want to share storage Connection String in Azure function , how about storing Connection String in Azure key vault and use Azure function MSI to get it, so that connection string will not cleartext in your Azure function. Details see here : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/

Comment: Thanks Stanley. Unfortunately, when I say I don't want to share it, i mean that the function must never have access to the connection string and never be able to perform any other actions on the storage account, beyond read-only consumption of any new blobs.

It's about security and responsibilities: the storage account belongs to one team and service, which holds data for multiple teams and services.

Those other teams and services must only be able to access data according to the permissions defined by RBAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2021-09-06 this is now possible by:

1. Using Event Grid for the events (not the blob trigger directly, which still requires the same ConnectionString as before)
2. Use the approach described here to read the content of the blob: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/functions-storage-managed-identity/using-managed-identity-between-azure-functions-and-azure-storage/